# Can't open up WordPress website after changing url

Tags: wordpress, apache, http, https, virtualhost

I have a WordPress website running on `me.commerce.loc` virtual host domain. I changed the siteurl and home from `http://me.commerce.loc` to `https://me.commerce.loc` from my wp-admin settings by mistake. Now when I try to go to `me.commerce.loc`, it gives me an error saying `this website cannot provide a secure connection. ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT`.

I have tried to change the siteurl and home back to `http://me.commerce.loc` from `wp-options` table in database, but it doesn't work. I also added `define('WP_HOME','http://me.commerce.loc');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://me.commerce.loc');` in my `wp-config.php` file, but no success. Ultimately I deleted my project from htdocs and added it back again, but same error.

Comment: open in incognito window or in mobile or other network.I think network cached your website.

Comment: I got stuck on this for hours xD. Yes it was the network caching the website. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried going to the site in incognito? 
if you visited the site with the wrong URL first you're browser wil remember this URL.